# How do I create a sql dependency on a table in sql server 2000 and asp.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldependency

I need to create `sql dependenc`y on a table in `sql server 2000` in my `asp.net 2.0` pages.

What are the required actions and what is the best way? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft has a great tutorial on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx) which basically explains that you need to enable it using the [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx) utility or the [SqlCacheDependencyAdmin class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependencyadmin(VS.80).aspx)